# Feature Selection in TfIdfVectorizer

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, tfidfvectorizer

I want to classify two groups of documents using `TfIdfVectorizer`. But `TfIdfVectorizer` lists words based on frequency in both documents. For instance, in the example below, the words Tom and Jerry are the defining words, while the `max_features` parameter retrieves the frequent ones ('hi', 'is', 'my'). Obviously, the document differences are important for classification, not similarities. So, how can I extract the determinant words in each document? also, stopword removal does not really help in this scenario.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd


corpus = [
    'hi, my name is Tom.',
    'hi, my name is Jerry.'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=3, ngram_range=(1, 1))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()


df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

The output:

```
,hi,is,my
0,0.5773502691896258,0.5773502691896258,0.5773502691896258
1,0.5773502691896258,0.5773502691896258,0.5773502691896258
```

The expected output:

```
,jerry,tom
0,0.0,0.5749618667993135
1,0.5749618667993135,0.0
```